# How to solve Bad URL error in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am creating a simple application in android studio for managing a device connected via wifi using the Volley library.
When I run the application, I get the following error.

*java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL 192.168.137.139:8081/zeroconf/switch
at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:171)
at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:120)
at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:87)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 192.168.137.139:8081/zeroconf/switch
at java.net.URL.(URL.java:601)
at java.net.URL.(URL.java:498)
at java.net.URL.(URL.java:447)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.executeRequest(HurlStack.java:92)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:131)
at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:120) 
at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:87)*

How can I solve?

```js
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.text.BreakIterator;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
    SwitchCompat switchButton;
    LinearLayout imageViewLight;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    TextView buttonState;
    private StringRequest mStringRequest;
    private String url = "192.168.137.139:8081/zeroconf/switch";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        switchButton=findViewById(R.id.switchButton);
        imageViewLight=findViewById(R.id.linearL);
        TextView buttonState;
        buttonState = findViewById(R.id.buttonState);

        switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                sendAndRequestResponse();                
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendAndRequestResponse() {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        mStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                TextView myTextView;
                if (switchButton.isChecked()) {
                    imageViewLight.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.light__02);
                    buttonState.setText("State : ON");
                } else {
                    imageViewLight.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.light__01);
                    buttonState.setText("State : OFF");
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Log.i(TAG,"Error :" + error.toString());
            }
        });

        mRequestQueue.add(mStringRequest);  

    }
}
```

Comment: You must be getting some response code like 404 or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to declare your URL like this:

```
private String URL = "http://192.168.137.139:8081/zeroconf/switch";
```

There are some additional setups if you want to make an HTTP request by Volley while using HTTP instead of HTTPS.
If you are working with HTTP add this to your Manifest:

```
        <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false" />
```

And create this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <network-security-config xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res                 /android">
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

Don't forget to test your URL using Postman to make sure your URL is working or not.

Comment: So do you advise me to delete that Private?
That xml file what do I call it and what is it for?
Yes yes, I checked with Postman and the URL is working correctly

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it got resolved by calling [MoPub.initializeSdk()](https://developers.mopub.com/publishers/android/initialize/)  on a java side.

Comment: as i am new to android programming, can you kindly tell me how to do it with my code?

Comment: can you refer (https://developers.mopub.com/publishers/android/initialize/) to this link?. It might be helpful.